# Virtual jukebox

Tags: music

Are there any music services (similar to Grooveshark) that allow multiple people to share a play queue? I live in Australia, so I'd like something with availability outside of the US.

Update: Grooveshark is now available in Australia

Answer (score 1):

I was going to recommend [turntable.fm](http://turntable.fm), but I just gave it a quick spin around the Google News machine and find that international users are now locked out of their service. Bummer!

But! I believe [Listening Room](http://listeningroom.net) will do something similar, although each user in a room has to upload a song to play it (instead of selecting it from an online catalog). I can't find any documentation on whether or not it's available outside the United States (and being in the States I can't test that!), however.